# Area of a triangle with too many variables

Tags: geometry

In a UK A-Level Mathematics practice question on surds I have the following question,

> The area of a triangle is given as $(16 + 4\sqrt 5)cm^2$
>
> The base of the triangle is $(7 - \sqrt 5)cm$, and the perpendicular height is $(p + q\sqrt 5)cm$.
>
> Find the values of $p$ and $q$.

Using the $Area = \frac{base * height}{2}$ triangle rule and doing churning through the maths I get the relation $p = 4q$ but without another rule-about-triangles this remains unconstrained.

Given it's not possible to solve for 2 variables with 1 equation is there a way to get constant values for $p$ and $q$?

Edit: The $p = 4q$ might be wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height is $$\dfrac{2\cdot\text{Area}}{\text{base}}=\frac{2(16+4\sqrt{5})}{7-\sqrt{5}}=6+2\sqrt{5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Are you given that p and q are rational numbers?  If you are then you get two equations for p and q.

1/2 base times height= area gives
$(1/2)(7- \sqrt{5})(p+ q\sqrt{5})= 16+ 4\sqrt{5}$
$7p- 5q+ (7q- p)\sqrt{5}= 32- 8\sqrt{5}$

**If** p and q are rational numbers then we must have 
$7p- 5q= 32$ and $7q- p= -8$.

Comment: The point that's essential here is that $\sqrt 5$ is irrational, so $1,\sqrt5$ are linearly independent over the rationals. From this we deduce that if $a+b\sqrt 5 = c+d\sqrt 5$, with $a,b,c,d$ rational numbers, then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Answer (score 1):

$$h=\dfrac{2\cdot\text{Area}}{\text{base}}=$$

$$\frac{2(16+4\sqrt{5})}{7-\sqrt{5}}=$$

$$\frac{2(16+4\sqrt{5})(7+\sqrt 5)}{(7-\sqrt{5})(7+\sqrt 5)}=$$

$$\frac {264+88\sqrt 5}{44}= 
  6+2\sqrt{5}.$$